# Internal speaker not detected. What can I do?

Tags: windows-7, speakers

My machine (win 7 home premium) has an internal speaker but does not detect it. Which I detect in a non-working monitor loudspeaker. I would like to set the default for the internal loudspeaker but it does not detect it so I do not know. What do I have to do with the sound driver? What is the name of the driver that I have to install?

Comment: Have you checked the monitor's support page to see if there's a driver for the built in speaker?

Comment: *"...an internal speaker"* -- A single cone speaker?  PC audio typically needs at least stereo (2 channels) speakers